# Parsing Windows event logs using KQL

Tags: windows, parsing, logging, kql

```
Permissions on an object were changed.

Subject: 
  Security ID: S-1-5-18 
  Account Name: ABCD$ 
  Account Domain: TASKGROUP
  Logon ID: 0x3E7 

Object: 
  Object Server: Security 
  Object Type: Token 
  Object Name: - 
  Handle ID: 0xa08 

Process: 
  Process ID: 0x9a4 
  Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe 

Permissions Change: 
  Original Security Descriptor: D:(Y;;GF;;;SY)(Y;;YT;;;SJ) 
  New Security Descriptor: D:(B;;T;;;SY)(A;;FV;;;OW)(B;;T;;;S-1-5-86-615999462-62705297-2911207457-59056572-3668589837)]
```

How to parse this kind of Windows event logs using KQL? Each field I want it to be one column.

Comment: It would help if you could provide the matching output for the input you've provided, in tabular format. Plus, please indicate if this "schema" is constant, or if fields may change across different records

Comment: @YoniL. Hi, this schema is not constant. I am looking for a solution that can make it to suit for every different logs

Comment: If it's for this specific event, it is possible by looking up the event schema and parsing it, if it is for all windows events, its near impossible as there are too many scenarios. If you are collecting via the MMA / AMA agents, then the common properties for all events will be mapped to the SecurityEvent / Event / WindowsEvent tables (which table depends on what you are collecting and how). However event specific properties could be endless and have their own schemas in some instances.